# Using summation gives widly different function approximation than integration

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, summation, fourier-series, data-analysis

I am trying to create a discrete fourier series that describes a data set.

You may have to look at [this desmos I made](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ueocrekfmy) to fully understand what I am talking about here.

When I calculate coefficients like

$$
\begin{align}
a_0&=\frac{1}{2\pi }\sum _{i=1}^{N-1}y_i\Delta x \\
a_k&=\frac{1}{\pi }\sum _{i=1}^{N-1}y_i\cos \left(kx_i\right)\Delta x \\ 
b_k&=\frac{1}{\pi }\sum _{i=1}^{N-1}y_i\sin \left(kx_i\right)\Delta x \\
\end{align}
$$

where $N$ is number of data points I have, and $x$ and $y$ are my data values, in my case:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
\text{x} & \text{y} \\ \hline
-3.14 & -8.87 \\ \hline
-2.44 & -4.97 \\ \hline
-1.75 & -2.05 \\ \hline
-1.05 & -0.10 \\ \hline
-0.35 & 0.88 \\ \hline
0.35 & 0.88 \\ \hline
1.05 & -0.10 \\ \hline
1.75 & -2.05 \\ \hline
2.44 & -4.97 \\ \hline
3.14 & -8.87 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

But, using these values for the coefficients gives a really ugly $F(x)$:

$$
F\left(x\right)=a_0+\sum _{k=1}^8\left(a_k\cos \left(kx\right)+b_k\sin \left(kx\right)\right)
$$
[image]

However, if I change the summations to (IMO, equivalent) integrations, the approximation becomes sooooo much better:

$$
\begin{align}
a_0&=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }f\left(x\right)dx \\
a_k&=\frac{1}{\pi }\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }f\left(x\right)\cos \left(kx\right)dx \\
b_k&=\frac{1}{\pi }\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }f\left(x\right)\sin \left(kx\right)dx \\
\end{align}
$$
[image]

---

What am I doing wrong in the case of the summations to get that weird result? How do I fix this?

Comment: What $f(x)$ did you use in the second case? If you input ten values of the function (in the discrete case) vs. *every single value* of the function (in the continuous case), then of course you'll get better agreement in the latter case.

Comment: @GregMartin in both cases $y = f(x) = 1-x^2$

Comment: @GregMartin I'd expect the approximation to be slightly better perhaps, but not so massively. Have a look at the desmos, mess around with the upper summation limit on $F(x)$. Increasing it should increase accuracy